# MediaStore returned thumbnail path but File object giving file not exist - Android

Tags: android, mediastore

I got the thumbnail path of videos using `CursorLoader`. MediaStore is giving me the thumbnail path. Now When I check for if the thumbnail path exists or not, it's giving me that `file not exists`.

I've found thumbnail path using

```
Cursor c = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external"), project,  selection, selectionArgs, null).loadInBackground();
while(c.moveToNext()) {

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    paths=c.getString(1);
 }
```

Toasts showing a path like

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1411810114902.jpg
```

So I decided to check if file exists before doing something with it.

```
File file = new File(paths);
if (file.exists())
{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Surprisingly it's showing `NO` how! What mediastore gave me?? My main intention is to manipulate or convert the thumbnail image into **base64** string. But `decodeFile` method was giving `File not exists` error so I tried to check the existence of the file.

Why is this giving me error like file not exists when filepath is given by the mediaStore. What's going on? What I'm missing? What's the way to manipulate/access thumbnail image?

Comment: do all thumbnails , have the same problem? sometimes, the media store db is not updated after an image is deleted.

Comment: Yes. If I put the file checking inside the loop all paths are showing `NO`

Comment: Can you show your entire code what is each object in the Cursor loader can you show the corresponding values as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same issue few days ago. The reason is due to some internal memory management process, sometimes it store images either in `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` or `/storage/emulated/1/DCIM`.

To deal with this, its always recommended that ***Create your new folder for saving newly captured image from camera & access it from that folder***.

Also, Check it on real device it may because there is no sd card for emulator & So it gets confused where to store if internal memory gets full so it jumps to sd card dcim folder.

Comment: No matter wherever it save doesn't mediaStore should give me the right path? My paths are not static, they are collected from mediaStore query.
And thumbnails are not from captured image/video. These are saved videos in sdcard. Downloaded/transfered videos can be there. So I have no control over where thumbnails can be saved.

Comment: Check it on real device it may because there is no sd card for emulator

Comment: So it gets confused where to store if internal memory gets full so it jumps to sd card dcim folder

Comment: Yeah working on real device. Strange!!!!!!! Those paths were generated from emulator too. How can it generate path that can't be found by itself. Funny! Anyway solved. Thank you. You can update the answer with your suggestion, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the user deletes an image file from an file manager, and if the file manager does not send proper broadcasts to notify the media scanner, then the thumbnail info of this image would still exist in the provider.

I had a similar problem, I only wanted to get images that still exist on the sdcard, because I want to display all the images in a grid, and then when the user clicks on one item, let the user view the large image, but then some images only have their thumbs there, not the real image.

First it is worth noting that modifying the selection parameters in the `CursorLoader` would not work, because we can not make the `CursorLoader` to check if the file exists or not.
My workaround is to use a custom `CursorWrapper` that skips rows with bad files

```
public class CursorWithDefectiveRows extends CursorWrapper {
    private static final String TAG = CursorWithDefectiveRows.class.getSimpleName();

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private DefectiveCursorRowChecker mChecker;
    private List<Integer> mGoodRowCounts;

    private Map<Integer, Integer> mCache;


    public static interface DefectiveCursorRowChecker {
        boolean isDefective(Cursor cursor);

        public static final DefectiveCursorRowChecker IMAGE_FILE_EXISTS_CHECKER = new DefectiveCursorRowChecker() {
            @Override
            public boolean isDefective(Cursor cursor) {
                File imageFile = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)););
                return !(imageFile.exists() && imageFile.length() > 0);
            }
        };
    }


    public CursorWithDefectiveRows(Cursor cursor, DefectiveCursorRowChecker checker) {
        super(cursor);

        mCursor = cursor;
        mChecker = checker;

        init(cursor, checker);
    }

    private void init(Cursor cursor, DefectiveCursorRowChecker checker) {
        mGoodRowCounts = new ArrayList<>();


        mGoodRowCounts.add(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            if (checker.isDefective(cursor)) {
                mGoodRowCounts.add(mGoodRowCounts.get(i));
            } else {
                mGoodRowCounts.add(mGoodRowCounts.get(i) + 1);
            }
        }

        mCache = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public int getCompressedPosition(int cursorPosition) {
        return mGoodRowCounts.get(cursorPosition);
    }

    public int getCursorPosition(int compressedPosition) {
        if (compressedPosition < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (compressedPosition > getCount() - 1) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }

        if (mCache.containsKey(compressedPosition)) {
            return mCache.get(compressedPosition);
        }

        int index = Collections.binarySearch(mGoodRowCounts, compressedPosition);
        if (index < 0) {
            return index;
        }

        while (index < mGoodRowCounts.size() - 1 && mGoodRowCounts.get(index).intValue() == mGoodRowCounts.get(index + 1).intValue()) {
            index++;
        }

        mCache.put(compressedPosition, index);
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mGoodRowCounts.get(mGoodRowCounts.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition() {
        return getCompressedPosition(mCursor.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean move(int offset) {
        return moveToPosition(getPosition() + offset);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        return mCursor.moveToPosition(getCursorPosition(position));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToFirst() {
        return moveToPosition(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToLast() {
        return moveToPosition(getCount() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToNext() {
        return moveToPosition(getPosition() + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean moveToPrevious() {
        return moveToPosition(getPosition() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFirst() {
        return getPosition() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLast() {
        return getPosition() == getCount() - 1;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean requery() {
        boolean result = super.requery();

        if (result) {
            init(mCursor, mChecker);
        }

        return result;
    }



}
```

the main job of this class happens in `init` and `getCursorPosition` methods, which I'm not going to explain here right now, they are not very complicated after all.
to use this class, just use

```
Cursor cursor = new CursorWithDefectiveRows(loadedCursor, CursorWithDefectiveRows.DefectiveCursorRowChecker.IMAGE_FILE_EXISTS_CHECKER)
```

and this result cursor skips all bad files, it can be used with a `CursorAdapter` right away

Comment: @Skullper Ouch, I regret saying that the codes are not very complicated now, there surely is some complicated stuff going on there. But I still have my app developed 2 years ago on my s9+, and it seems working fine.